# How to use the Inverse Transform Method to generate samples from f(x)= 1/12* 3√ x where 0 ≤ x ≤ 8

Tags: random

I am trying to use the Inverse Transform Method to generate samples from this equation 1/12 * cube root of x where 0<=x<8. I have tried following some of the tutorials on the site with no success, please help me. I am trying to revise for an end of semester examination.
How do I use the steps below to generate samples from the equation. Pardon my equation expressed in words I do not know how to use the formatting tools provided by the site to format the expression

a)  Let F(x), x E R denote any cumulative distribution function

b)   Let F−1(y)F−1(y), y∈[0,1]y∈[0,1] denote the inverse function and define X=F−1(U)X=F−1(U), where U∼U(0,1)U∼U(0,1)

c)   Generate u∼U(0,1)  u∼U(0,1).

d)  Set u=1−e−0.05xu=1−e−0.05x (CDF of Exponential)

e)  Solving for x, yields: x=−1*0.05*log(u)

Comment: You ignore d) and e) which are specific to the exponential context, and instead solve $F(x)=u$ where $F$ is your CDF in your actual problem, which is to say $x^{4/3}/16$. (You can ignore the fact that $F$ is not equal to $x^{4/3}/16$ everywhere because the solution you want will be in $[0,8]$ anyway.)

Comment: Would appreciate it if you posted a well defined step by step answer

Comment: Given what you have already written, the only "math" step left to do is to solve $x^{4/3}/16=u$ which is not difficult to do. The rest is programming, which is somewhat off-topic here.

Comment: okay i solve for that for the rest of values between 0 and 8?

Comment: You solve it for $u \in [0,1]$, which will end up hitting every $x \in [0,8]$.

Comment: Okay, does this site support dark mode?I just checked my profile tab and its not there